# How to avoid redirect after execute action, use "Struts"

Tags: internationalization, struts

I'm trying to create internationalization, using struts, and after execute an action, a lost my parameters after '`?`'. How I could to save it.

```java
public class ChangeLocaleAction extends DispatchAction {

    public ActionForward russian(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
                                 HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        request.getSession().setAttribute(
                Globals.LOCALE_KEY, new Locale("ru"));

//        return mapping.findForward(request.getHeader("referer").split("/")[3].split("\\.")[0]);
        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }

    public ActionForward english(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
                                 HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        request.getSession().setAttribute(
                Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.ENGLISH);

//        return mapping.findForward(request.getHeader("referer").split("/")[3].split("\\.")[0]);
        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
}
```

And Struts-config code:

```xml
<action path="/change-locale"
                name="localeForm"
                validate="false"
                type="com.epam.testapp.presentation.action.ChangeLocaleAction" parameter="language">
            <forward name="success" path="/" redirect="true"/>
</action>
```

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have tried so far and an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to save parameters from get request, which after '?' sign

Answer (score 0):

You wanna do:
`request.getParameter("parameter name")` it will return a String containing the value of the parameter.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)